# Adding counter to reducer in Hadoop Map-Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to write a map reduce job and want to add a counter to my reducer. However when I run the job the counter does not seem to appear in the output.

Currently I am using the line (Java):

```
context.getCounter(ReducerCounters.COUNTDISTINCT).increment(1);
```

To be honest I'm not 100% sure its possible to use a counter like this on a reducer. If anyone knows if this is possible or impossible please let me know. I can't seem to find any reliable examples of a counter on a reducer online.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following are my imports :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counters;
```

This is present in my driver class as an enum.

```
 public enum ReducerCounters {
    COUNTDISTINCT
   };
```

And this is present in my driver's run function.

```
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    Counters cn=job.getCounters();
    // Find the specific counters that you want to print
    Counter c1=cn.findCounter(ReducerCounters.COUNTDISTINCT);
    System.out.println("Displaying just the value " + c1.getValue());
```

Also make sure you are using the latest hadoop client version in your pom file.  Don't use the last released hadoop-core version since it is not updated. I just tested it. Counters work both in my mapper and reducer.